# IOS Safari Open in App banner position problem

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

When i run my website on safari, button stick on the bottom side.

Examples:

this is normal one

[image: this is normal one]

but this is silly

[image: but this is silly]

any suggestion do you have?

also this is button div's code

```
position: fixed;
width: calc(100% - 30px);
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 70px 100px 80px #fff;
box-shadow: 0 70px 100px 80px #fff;
z-index: 10000;
margin: 15px !important;
```

Comment: Have you found a solutions for this issue yet?

Comment: @omar just checking, in case you got a solution for this.